# function css() on a non-object

Tags: facebook, cakephp

I have encountered an error with my development. Trying to do Facebook Authentication basics on CakePHP and doing the debug activity and stumbledupon this error, which i cannot fix for now. Maybe there's some solution to this? or possibly an issue that was not yet addressed?

> Error: Call to a member function css() on a non-object     File:
>   C:\wamp\www\facebook_example\app\View\Layouts\facebook.ctp     Line: 3

If you're going to see Line3:

```
  <?php echo $html->css('cake.generic'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error will occur if you attempt to call a method on a variable that is not an object. Within CakePHP this can be encountered on the HTML helper if you:

- Don't specify to include the helper in your controller, or
- Don't call the helper correctly.

So ensure that your helper is included in the `$helpers` array on your controller:

```
public MyController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array(
        'Html',
        'Form',
    );
}
```

And lastly, call the helper correctly in your view:

```
<?php
$this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

Its important to note that while CakePHP **1.x** supports the following format:

```
$html->css()
```

this is no longer supported in CakePHP **2.x** and beyond. The new format is:

```
$this->Html->css()
```

Hope that helps!